# NSIndexPath save to another entity

Tags: mysql, ios, uitableview, core-data, entity

I am almost done researching for my application. The last thing that I need to be able to learn how to do is the following situation: Let's say I have created a UItableview drilldown app, but once the user gets to the end of that drill down (their choices on a specific dog product for instance are now very specific), they can save that information. What I want my app to do here is, at the end of the drilldown, save their entire nsindexpath as another entity so that I can send this information later up to my MySQL database. **My question is, how could I re-save an nsstring from an nsindexpath in another entity?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with runmads suggestions. CoreData will probably make your life easier in the long run. To answer your question though:

Don't save the table view's NSIndexPath. The selection index path is a **view** related property (in MVC terms). Your users choice belongs to the **model** domain. It's bad practice to mix the two and if you later insert new choices in one of your tables, your stored index paths will become invalid.

Instead create something like a UserChoice object or a dictionary or an array which you can pass down your tableview controllers as the user drills down. When the user selects a cell, add the **primary key** of the associated data object to your array. At the end, store the primary keys you've collected along the way into your database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start writing code instead of researching your entire app's architecture before you start it. You really only will learn from actually programming.
2. Use Core Data

Use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to obtain the selected tableview cell's indexPath and store the indexPath or the data as needed.